# How to attach real data (not testdata) to a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a fairly simple list app with SwiftUI with a ContentView and DetailView.

However, in all the tutorials I have seen, the data source being passed to both views is only "testData" and the data source is only defined in the #if DEBUG part.

How do I define within the ContentView itself which array it should load data from?

I've created several arrays of data, but I don't understand where outside of the #if DEBUG that this data is actually accessed.

```
import SwiftUI

 struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var store = GrapeStore()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(store.grapes) { grape in
                GrapeCell(grape: grape)
                }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Wine grapes")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        .listStyle(.grouped)
    }

}

}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    Group {
        ContentView(store: GrapeStore(grapes: AGrapes))

        ContentView(store: GrapeStore(grapes: testData))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)

    }
}
}
#endif

struct GrapeCell : View {
let grape: Grape

var body: some View {
    return NavigationLink(destination: GrapeDetail(grape: grape)) {
        Image(systemName: "photo")

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(grape.name)
            Text("\(grape.type) grape")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
}
```

I manage to pull data from the ACGrapes and testData arrays, but that is only in the previews. How do I decide what data should be actually pulled?

Comment: What's in the DEBUG section is test data - but *only* for Xcode previews. You can attach data (either static or dynamic) by binding your list to an array. A hardcoded one is static, and a "stateful" one is dynamic. Here's a good resource (careful, from beta 1) on all things SwiftUI. Scroll down to the section on lists for help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/

Comment: thanks, that was all I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data from scene delegate file of your projects too.

Comment: This really isn't a good answer - it isn't complete. You can easily populate a `List` from a simple local variable (it's called a static list) or from a `@State` variable (that's a dynamic list). Please delete this answer.